Are sleep and reset on DRV8825 tied up to GND?
I am working on a project that has a servo and a stepper motor, so I build a circuit which have both the driver and lm7805.
The problem is that the regulator overheated very quickly. I traced the wires and noticed that the 5 V ouput of the regulator was shorted to GND.
I desoldered the whole circuit and noticed with my multimeter that sleep and reset pins of the driver were shorted to GND, with only 20 ohms between them.
Is that normal for the driver or is it broken?

